# Enabling SNMP on Windows Server 2003 SP2 shows printer as Offline

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, printing, snmp

I've tried this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946198
and no luck!

Any ideas? I've been Googling for 2 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable SNMP and enter credentials on the printer's management page first, then enable on the server. That resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is SNMP v1 enabled on the printer? Has the SNMP get community name been changed?

If SNMP v1 has been disabled, the printer won't respond. If the SNMP get community name has been changed from the default (usually "public"), then the new SNMP get community name must be entered into the port tab (printer properties, ports tab, configure port, community name field)

Comment: unfortunately, it's when you enable SNMP on the printer it shows offline. The community name is correct, and it appears to be a known issue with Server 2003 - however, the "fix" from Microsoft didn't work...